# Xpath select all tr without table with id=x

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

Hello i need to select all tr,but in some tr i have a table with `id=WHITE_BANKTABLE`.

I need to select only Tr that dont't have this table with id.

My html

```
    <table id=mytable_body>
        <TR id=TR_ROW_BANKTABLE class=TR_ROW_BANKTABLE style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f6f8fa" align=right bgColor=#f6f8fa>
        <TD noWrap align=right w_idth="190">  </TD>
        <TD align=right>010073/15922</TD>
     </TR>


>   **//This Tr with TABLE id=WHITE_BANKTABLE i don't need**

    <TR>
        <TD colSpan=8 align=center>
        <TABLE id=WHITE_BANKTABLE cellSpacing=0 borderColorDark=#edf0f5 cellPadding=3 width="100%" bgColor=white borderColorLight=#edf0f5 border=1 isWhiteTable="Y">
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=TR_BANKTABLE align=right vAlign=top>
        <TD> sdfsd </TD>

        <TD>sdfs</TD>
    </TR>
    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    </TD>
    </TR>
        <TR id=TR_ROW_BANKTABLE class=TR_ROW_BANKTABLE style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f6f8fa" align=right bgColor=#f6f8fa>
        <TD noWrap align=right w_idth="190">  </TD>
        <TD align=right>010073/15922</TD>
     </TR>

    </table>
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the above is correctly formatted as XML (insert missing double quotes):

```
var q = 
xml.XPathSelectElements(@"/tr[not(descendant::table[@id = 'WHITE_BANKTABLE'])]");
```